# how can i get json object data in my url in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i have this json object

```
    blog:{
      "_id": "62567252370e769a8a93a517", 
      "title": "my trip to zanziar"
    }
```

i'm trying to show  in my url

```
http://localhost:8082/blog/my-trip-to-zanziar
```

in my url

but i'm getting

```
http://localhost:8082/blog/my%20trip%20to%20zanziar
```

and its not displaying any data

this is how i go to the route

```
 <router-link :to="`/blog/${blog._title}`">
                
                </router-link>
```

this is my router

```
  {
    path: "/blog/:title",
  },
```

this is how i diplay to get the details under the title

```
mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/api/blogs/${this.$route.params.title}`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.blog = response.data.blog;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

please how i can go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) where appropriate to replace empty spaces with hyphens:

```html
 <router-link :to="`/blog/${blog?._title?.replaceAll(' ', '-')}`" />
```

You might also consider making the formatted string it's own [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) if you need to perform the replacement more than once in your component.

Comment: i'm getting  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')

Comment: your `blog._title` must not be fully defined at the time of component creation.  that's ok.  I've updated my answer to utilize [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).  this will prevent any errors while the blog object data is still loading.

Comment: If I remove _ it's works but it does display the data under the route

Answer (score 0):

you should add one more property like a slug in the blog object.

```
this.blog = { ...blog, slug: blog.title.replaceAll(' ','-').toLowerCase()}
```

now, you can use the slug in the router link.

```
<router-link :to="`/blog/${blog.slug}`"> ... </router-link>
```